# Can I make android app that will cover half of the screen only

Tags: android, call

I made  broadcast receiver when receive calls I want to add a button( besides answer and      decline)that will do a certain function, so I see 2 solutions one is that I make ( if it's possible half screen transparent activity that will have the button but not block the answer and decline buttons, or the second solution that I see is to make something like BIG CALLER PICTURE apps that there is on the play.google can anyone refer me to some good examples. THX

```
  public class CallReceiveD extends BroadcastReceiver {
private ITelephony telephonyService;
String phoneNumber;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // i will call the intent here

            }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You definitely can create an activity as a dialog that would take up part of the screen.  Although I am not sure this will accomplish what you want because by opening the new activity the phone activity should get onPause called and will probably mess up your flow.  Maybe try opening an activity and define in the activity in the manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

And see if that works at all for what you want to do.  Then you can tweek the dim around the activity it's location,size, etc.

Comment: I think i want to try this as dialog but because i am very new to this can u give me an example of what should stand in the manifest, how to create the class and the xml file ?

Comment: just create an android project and you will get a mainactivity of some sort created for you.  Then go to the manifest xml and add that attribute to the mainactivity definition.  run the app and you should get just a dialog placed over whatever was open beforehand

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: @LadyWoodi I don't think Toasts will always receive touch events though.

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ScreenD.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);

my intent wont start? i call it in the ONReceive metod from broadcast receiver

Comment: are you getting an error in logcat?  try changing startActivity to context.startActivity

Comment: I did that , may be the error is because public class CallReceiveD extends BroadcastReceiver {ONreceive{here i call the intent}}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will help but there is a framework called StandOut for "floating" apps. Maybe it could help you ...

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531

It provides ways to create app windows floating over the screen instead of taking up the whole. You can still interact with the app below. The thread provides a lot of examples, maybe there's something for you in it.

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but from what I know you will not be able to start a half screen intent (Activity). You can do a transparent activity but it will block system buttons underneath. I would say you have to try overriding the system calling receiver tool too achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create a partial screen activity. Nothing underneath the new activity, if started with a dialog theme as MikeIsrael suggests.    Simple write an Activity as you normally would, but give it layout_width and layout_height of your choosing - says 300x400dp.

Then can then use onAttachWindow to set the size and location. This example sets a window to be on the top right of the display, but below the actionBAr

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();


    lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    lp.width = (int)(400 * screenInfo.density);
    lp.x = screenInfo.widthPixels - lp.width;
    lp.y = actionBarHeight;
    getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, lp);
```

}

Note that although the Gravity says top left, the X,Y determines where I place the window